# C# CosmosDb Query error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<xxxx>' to

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, json-deserialization

I have this CosmosDb call to retrieve a list of leases.

```
List<Lease> leases = null;

var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery<List<Lease>>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Leases"), 
    "select * from c");

leases = response;
```

but I get the CS0266 error at leases = response;
The full error message (just to get more words / details than code)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Demo.Shared.Lease>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Demo.Shared.Lease>'

If I try this though, it works for one record. Well no Exception and the response is null.

```
var response = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Lease>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Users"), queryOptions)
                       .Where(f => f.lease == "3114/968").AsEnumerable().ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```

The Lease class:

```
public class Lease
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string lease { get; set; }

    public Rent rent { get; set; }
}

public class Rent
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateTo { get; set; }
    public double? amountIncTax { get; set; }
    public string datePaid { get; set; }
    public double? amountExTax { get; set; }
    public double? taxAmount { get; set; }
    public string chequeNumber { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string receiptNumber { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdDate { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON in Cosmos db:

```
{
"lease": "E16/445",
"rent": {
    "type": "Rent Payment",
    "dateFrom": "2015-04-09T00:00:00.0000000",
    "dateTo": "2016-04-08T00:00:00.0000000",
    "amountIncTax": 244.2,
    "datePaid": "2015-04-01T00:00:00.0000000",
    "amountExTax": 244.2,
    "taxAmount": 0,
    "chequeNumber": "ONLINE",
    "comment": null,
    "receiptNumber": "MT-210010243602",
    "createdBy": "SBM\\Sandy.Thuel",
    "createdDate": "2015-04-21T07:36:56.1400000",
    "modifiedBy": "SBM\\Sandy.Thuel",
    "modifiedDate": "2015-04-21T07:36:56.4830000"
},
"id": "337ed2fa-44f3-4474-9b51-923c6635fb11",
"r_id": etc,
```

}

[image]
Any ideas please,

TIA

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `Lease` as the type argument, not `List<Lease>`, and then actually materialize the query with `.ToList()` (disclaimer: I don't use CosmosDB).

Comment: Shouldn't you use `client.CreateDocumentQuery<Lease>` instead? That method is used to *start building a query*, it doesn't retrieve the results. You can add `Where` and `Select` clauses as needed after that. Finally, you need to call `ToList` or `ToListAsync` to actually execute the query and retrieve the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your IQueryable to a **`List`**. You can do this by adding `.ToList()` at the end of your Linq query. Also change the type as `<Lease>`. Try this query instead,

```
var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Lease>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Leases"), 
    "select * from c").ToList();
```

Comment: I tried that, got an error. re-trying it again,  Error;
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Demo.Shared.Rent' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array.

Comment: Maybe there is broken json in one of the items??

Comment: Seems you are using wrong type to cast it

Comment: I can;t see that my definition is incorrect, unless "id" must come after "rent" ?

Comment: Definition is definitely correct. This way works (for one record), 
    var response = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Lease>(
         UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Users"), queryOptions)
         .Where(f => f.lease == "3114/968").AsEnumerable().ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Except the response is null

Comment: Even tried changing my class properties all to string and running this: (which works, and retrieves a record )
var response2 = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Lease>(
      UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Leases"), queryOptions)
      .Where(f => f.lease == "E16/445").AsEnumerable().ToArray().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: There is broken  JSON in the document.    Select *  breaks, but    .Where(f => f.lease == "E16/445").ToList();    works and returns a number of records.